# drawImage with ImageElement

Tags: dart, dart-html

Working: (document has a img tag with id="img" src="img.png", and it works)

```dart
  void test() {
    ImageElement img = query('#img');
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }
```

Not Working:

```dart
  void test() {
    ImageElement img = new ImageElement(src: 'img.png');
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }
```

so, why can't I use 'new ImageElement' instead of 'query' from the document ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the image hasn't loaded by the time you call drawImage (as opposed to when it is embedded in the page and loads before the dart code runs). You should listen for the onLoad stream and only draw the image once it is loaded:

```dart
  ImageElement img = new ImageElement(src: "img.png");
  img.onLoad.listen((value) => context.drawImage(img, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd elaborate on the image onload syntax a little, in reference onError, onDone and cancelOnError...

```dart
readFile() {
    ImageElement image = new ImageElement(src: "plant.png");
    document.body.nodes.add(image);
    image.onLoad.listen(onData, onError: onError, onDone: onDone, cancelOnError: true);
  }

  onData(Event e) {
    print("success: ");
  }

  onError(Event e) {
    print("error: $e");
  }

  onDone() {
    print("done");
  }
```