# Pass function as parameter in Dart

Tags: dart

Hello: I need pass a function (event handler) as parameter to other function site in other class:

```dart
classB
{
    ClassB(){}
/***/
    load (void onData(Event e))
    {
        ImageElement ie=new ImageElement();
        ie.onLoad.listen( onData );  
        ie.src='hello.png';
    } 

/***/

}

classA
{
    List<ClassB> lcb=new List();

    ClassA(){}
  /****/

    void handler(Event e) {
        /****/
    }

    myFunction() { 
       /***/
        for (var i=0; i < lcb.length; i++)
        {   
            ***
            lcb[i].load( handler );
            ***
        }
       /***/
    }
}
```

It seems right in principle, but does not work. The function that is passed is never executed.
Anyone have any idea what is the correct way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [drawImage with ImageElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739624/drawimage-with-imageelement)

Comment: Code works fine. Are you sure the image is loaded successfully? Also, please make sure that code you post is actually syntactically correct - Making corrections when testing code is a little bit tiring ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks good and should work especially after your recent update with `listen`. 
Why do you expect the `ImageElement` to fire. You have to assign a `src` and attach it to the DOM to make it load and fire `onload`.